# How to filter DIV as user types inside text input

Tags: jquery

I have a Search Box under which user types in , on this event i am trying to show only the relevant results present under div

This is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $('.searchtrainer').keyup(function()
        {
                var tr = $('.trainers_listWrap'); 
                if ($(this).val().length >= 2)
                {
                        var inputdata = $.trim($(".searchtrainer").val());

                        var noElem   = true;
                        var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();
                        el = tr.filter(function()
                        {
                                return $(this).find('.mt-radio').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
                        }); 
                        if (el.length >= 1)
                        {
                                noElem   = false;
                        }

                        tr.not(el).fadeOut();
                        el.fadeIn();

                }
                else
                {
                        tr.fadeIn(); 
                        $('#errmsgnovideos').hide();
                }
        })
});
```

This is my HTML

```
<div class="modal-body addTrainerContainer">
   <section class="addTrainer_search">
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control searchtrainer" placeholder="Search or Add trainer">

         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
   <section class="trainers_listWrap">
      <li>            <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline">ONE 
         <input type="radio" value="1" name="test">
         <span></span>
         </label>
      </li>
      <li>            <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline">TWO 
         <input type="radio" value="1" name="test">
         <span></span>
         </label>
      </li>
      <li>            <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline">THREE 
         <input type="radio" value="1" name="test">
         <span></span>
         </label>
      </li>
      <li>            <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline">Four 
         <input type="radio" value="1" name="test">
         <span></span>
         </label>
      </li>
      <li>            <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline">FIVE 
         <input type="radio" value="1" name="test">
         <span></span>
         </label>
      </li>
   </section>
</div>
```

This is my updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/364/

Could you please tell me how to resolve this ?

Comment: To answer this we need to know the general structure of your HTML. Now you have (invalid) HTML with a bunch of list items. But where does the content beneath each item go? Inside the list? Outside? Show the general HTML structure.

Comment: Resolve what? You need to be more specific, what are you expecting and what is the outcome/error you are getting?

Comment: First of all, there is no element with `searchtrainer` ID in your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **id="searchtrainer"** to your input box

```
<input type="text" id="searchtrainer" class="form-control searchtrainer" placeholder="Search or Add trainer">
```

And, Change your **tr** variable selector

```
var tr = $('.trainers_listWrap li');
```

And, Change your **tr.filter** return statement to

```
return $(this).find('.mt-radio').text().toLowerCase().match("^" + val );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `:contains`:

```js
$('.searchtrainer').keyup(function() {
  if($(this).val() == '') {
   $('.trainers_listWrap').children().show();
  } else {
   $('.trainers_listWrap').children().hide(); 
 $('.trainers_listWrap').find('li:contains("'+($(this).val()).toUpperCase()+'")').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body addTrainerContainer">
   <section class="addTrainer_search">
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control searchtrainer" placeholder="Search or Add trainer">
          
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
   <section class="trainers_listWrap">
      <li>            <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline">ONE 
         <input type="radio" value="1" name="test">
         <span></span>
         </label>
      </li>
      <li>            <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline">TWO 
         <input type="radio" value="1" name="test">
         <span></span>
         </label>
      </li>
      <li>            <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline">THREE 
         <input type="radio" value="1" name="test">
         <span></span>
         </label>
      </li>
      <li>            <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline">Four 
         <input type="radio" value="1" name="test">
         <span></span>
         </label>
      </li>
      <li>            <label class="mt-radio mt-radio-outline">FIVE 
         <input type="radio" value="1" name="test">
         <span></span>
         </label>
      </li>
   </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main issues in your code,

```
1) You have used class selector instead of ID selector
2) You have to use li text to compare but you have taken the whole section to compare.
```

Refer  : http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/363/